# After how many columns does the Pandas 'set_index' function stop being useful?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

As I understand it, the advantage to using the `set_index` function with a particular column is to allow for direct access to a row based on a value. As long as you know the value, this eliminates the need to search using something like `loc` thus cutting down the running time of the operation. Pandas also allows you to set multiple columns as the index using this function. My question is, after how many columns do these indexes stop being valuable? If I were to specify every column in my dataframe as the index would I still see increased speed in indexing rows over searching with `loc`?

Comment: The usefulness of having an index in a DataFrame exceeds just being used for increased speed with loc. It's useful to be able to join DFs by their indices. It's useful that Indices are usually omitted from most pandas DF operations, etc... The general question I'd ask myself when including a column in my index is: "Would it be useful to navigate my data based off of the value of this column"

Comment: Good points, though for this particular question I want to focus specifically on the effects that this type of indexing has on the speed of lookups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real downside of setting everything as index is buried deep in the advanced indexing docs of Pandas: [indexing can change the dtype of the column being set to index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#indexing-potentially-changes-underlying-series-dtype). I would expect you to encounter this problem before realizing the prospective performance benefit.

As for that performance benefit, you pay for indexing up front when you construct the `Series` object, regardless of whether you explicitly set them. AFAIK Pandas indexes everything by default. And as Jake VanderPlas puts it in his excellent book:

> If a Series is an analog of a one-dimensional array with flexible indices, a DataFrame is an analog of a two-dimensional array with both flexible row indices and flexible column names. Just as you might think of a two-dimensional array as an ordered sequence of aligned one-dimensional columns, you can think of a DataFrame as a sequence of aligned Series objects. Here, by "aligned" we mean that they share the same index.
>   -- Jake VanderPlas, [The Python Data Science Handbook](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.01-introducing-pandas-objects.html#DataFrame-as-a-generalized-NumPy-array)

So, the reason to set something as index is to make it easier for you to work with your data or to support your data access pattern, not necessarily for performance optimization like a database index.

Comment: That makes sense, although isn't there a potentially "unintended" performance optimization that manifests as a result of indexing? If I am looping through a list of values, each of which corresponds to what could be an index in my dataframe, is it not more efficient to do a lookup using each value as an index than to search for the presence of each value using something like `loc`?

Comment: Looping is an antipattern with python Pandas. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will make an effort to implement those techniques in my code moving forward. Nonetheless, that does not answer the question posed in the comment above.

Comment: Re: that question, I wouldn't expect much difference because `loc` operates on an index anyway.